# What distinguishes a command from needing () vs not?

Tags: python, pandas, function, methods

I recently spent way too long debugging a piece of code, only to realize that the issue was I did not include a () after a command. What is the logic behind which commands require a () and which do not?

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

col1=['a','b','c','d','e']
col2=[1,2,3,4,5]

df=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(col1,col2)),columns=['col1','col2'])

df.columns
```

Returns `Index(['col1', 'col2'], dtype='object')` as expected. If we use `.columns()` we get an error.

Other commands it is the opposite:

```
df.isna()
```

Returns:

```
    col1    col2
0   False   False
1   False   False
2   False   False
3   False   False
4   False   False
```

but `df.isna` returns:

```
<bound method DataFrame.isna of   col1  col2
0    a     1
1    b     2
2    c     3
3    d     4
4    e     5>
```

Which, while not throwing an error, is clearly not what we're looking for.

**What's the logic behind which commands use a () and which do not?**

I use pandas as an example here, but I think this is relevant to python more generally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because *functions* need parenthesis for their arguments, while *variables* do not, that's why it's `list.append(<item>)` but it's `list.items`.

If you call a function without the parenthesis like `list.append` what returns is a description of the function, **not** a description of what the function **does**, *but* a description of what it **is**.

As for classes, a call to a class *with* parenthesis initiates an object of that class, while a call to a class *without* the parenthesis point to the class *itself*, which means that if you were to execute `print(SomeClass)` you'd get `<class '__main__.SomeClass'>` which is a description of what it **is**, the same kind of response you'd get if you were to call a function *without* parenthesis.

Comment: can you comment on classes as well? Do they behave the same way as functions?

Comment: With *classes* if you call a class with the parenthesis you're instantiating an *object* from that class, but if you call a class without the parenthesis it'll, the same way as *functions*, return a description of what that **is**, so for example `print(TestClass)` will print saying something like `<class '__main__.TestClass'>`, while `TestClass()` returns an object of that class that has all of the class's functions and variables and is initialized according to the constructor of that class, etc.

Answer (score 3):

> What's the logic behind which commands use a () and which do not?

An object needs to have a [`__call__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) method associated with it for it to called as a function using `()`:

```
class Test:
    def __call__(self, arg):
        print("Called with", arg)

t = Test()  # The Test class object uses __call__ to create instances
t(5)  # Then this line prints "Called with 5"
```

So, the difference is that `columns` doesn't have a `__call__` method defined, while `Index` and `DataFrame` do.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR you just kinda have to know

Nominally, the parens are needed to call a function instead of just returning an object.

```
foo.bar    # get the bar object
foo.bar()  # call the bar object
```

Callable objects have a `__call__` method. When python sees the (), it knows to call `__call__`. This is done at the C level.

In addition, python has the concept of a property. Its a callable data object that looks like a regular data object.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._foo = "foo"

    @property
    def foo(self):
        return "I am " + self._foo

    @foo.setter
    def foo(self, val):
        assert isinstance(val, str)
        self._foo = val + " you bet"

f = Foo()
f.foo = "Hello"     # calls setter
print(f.foo)        # calls getter
```

Similarly, when python sees array notation `foo[1]` it will call an object's `__getitem__` or `__setitem__` methods and the object is free to overload that call in any way it sees fit.

Finally, the object itself can intercept attribute access with `__getattr__`, `__getattribute__` and `__setattr__` methods, leaving everything up in the air. In fact, python doesn't really know what getting and setting attributes means. It is calling these methods. Most objects just use the default versions inherited from `object`. If the class is implemented in C, there is no end to what could be going on in the background.

Python is a dynamic language and many packages add abstractions to make it easier (?) to use their services. The downside is that you may spend more time with help text and documentation than one may like.

Answer (score 0):

Object method vs Object attribute.

Objects has methods and attributes.
Methods require a parenthesis to call them -- even if the method does not require arguments.
Where as attributes are like variables are pointed to objects as the program progresses. You just call these attributes by their name (without parenthesis). Of course you may have to qualify both the methods and attributes with the object names as required.