# In Python Pandas, why do .describe and .describe() give different results?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using notebooks and I'm confused.

My original question was why `describe` is different from `describe()`.

So I read the excellent article [Purpose of calling function without brackets python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21785933/purpose-of-calling-function-without-brackets-python).

But so I keep don't understand why (maybe when?) to use `describe`, since it looks to return all the dataset...

Comment: Your links are to the same strange image. Please include the information as text instead

Comment: `.describe` is the method. `.describe()` calls it. [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html). What does the image have to do with anything?

Comment: Additionally, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65646020/what-distinguishes-a-command-from-needing-vs-not/65646642#65646642) question may also provide insight into when to use or not use parenthesis.

Comment: What @MZ is pointing out is that when you include the parenthesis, you call the method. When you fail to include the parenthesis, what returns is information regarding the method. You likely want to include the parenthesis (notice that they are included in all examples in the documentation).

Comment: Is not `describe`, without parenthesis, a attribute?

Comment: @Naivre yes it is. The attribute is the function.

Comment: @Naivre yes, methods *are* attributes

Comment: The confusing thing here is that the way the method is printed it prints the dataframe it is attached to. In any case, you would use that whenever you want to reference the method e.g. as a callback